# Databases, Tables, Columns in windows phone

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, multiple-columns

I have an app in windows phone 7.1 with local database sdf in isolated file.
Now in my current version I have the table:

```
[Table]
public class Employee
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string EmployeeFile
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeByte
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In next version of the app I want to add two more columns and look like this:

```
[Table]
public class Employee
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string EmployeeFile
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeExtn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeByte
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then if I change the code of the table the app crashes when a query is made.
How is possible to add these two columns if there are not exists in database?

I tried this code to update my database:

```
 using (Connection Empdb = new Connection(constant.strConnectionString))
            {
                if (Empdb.DatabaseExists())
                {
                    DatabaseSchemaUpdater dbUpdater = Empdb.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
                    // Add the column
                    try { dbUpdater.AddColumn<string>("EmployeeFile"); dbUpdater.Execute(); }
                    catch { /* Nothing */ }
                    try { dbUpdater.AddColumn<string>("EmployeeName"); dbUpdater.Execute(); }
                    catch { /* Nothing */ }
                    try { dbUpdater.AddColumn<string>("EmployeeType"); dbUpdater.Execute(); }
                    catch { /* Nothing */ }
                    try { dbUpdater.AddColumn<string>("EmployeeExtn"); dbUpdater.Execute(); }
                    catch { /* Nothing */ }
                    try { dbUpdater.AddColumn<string>("EmployeeByte"); dbUpdater.Execute(); }
                    catch { /* Nothing */ }
                }
            }
```

Every column goes into catch with this code, is this code right and in which table the column will be added?
In which table the column will be added?

Comment: When your application crashes, it does so because of an exception. You can catch that exception and it will tell you what is wrong.  Without that information you're just guessing.  Stop guessing.

Comment: use isolated tool explorer and check if database is generated as per your requirement. you can use sdf explorer to check database

Comment: my code is not buggy. But you have not copied the code correctly.Inside `<>` should have `Table` name not type of `column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be unrelated to your problem, since the answer from Aanabidden looks like the bug, but I see another problem with the code. The AddColumn() operations are cached inside of the database updater object and are executed at the Execute() call. But if the first column exists, every call to Execute() will try to add it again; the failure of the first Execute() call does not cause that operation to be removed from the database updater cache.

There is no reason to call any other AddColumn() or Execute() method once one of them fails because the cached operation will just keep throwing an exception.

The side effect is that if the first column already exists, none of the rest will get added.

The solution to the problem I see, again unrelated to your incorrect use of the 'string" type instead of the table name in the AddColumn type parameter, is to create a separate database updater object for each AddColumn/Execute pair. then a failure of one of them won't cause the rest to fail.

Again, this isn't whats going wrong in your code but is a bug if anything causes some columns to exist and others to not exist (like writing some other bug in the code and then distributing the app to customers like I did).

Answer (score 2):

You should use as below instead of column type you need to tell the table name
column type will be taken from the table class

```
try { dbUpdater.AddColumn<Employee>("EmployeeFile"); dbUpdater.Execute(); }
catch { /* Nothing */ }
```